# Moving Millions of items from one Storage Account to Another

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage, parallel.foreach

I have somewhere in the neighborhood of 4.2 million images I need to move from North Central US to West US, as part of a large migration to take advantage of Azure VM support (for those who don't know, North Central US does not support them). The images are all in one container, split into about 119,000 directories.

I'm using the following from the Copy Blob API:

```
public static void CopyBlobDirectory(
        CloudBlobDirectory srcDirectory,
        CloudBlobContainer destContainer)
{
    // get the SAS token to use for all blobs
    string blobToken = srcDirectory.Container.GetSharedAccessSignature(
        new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read |
                            SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(14)
        });

    var srcBlobList = srcDirectory.ListBlobs(
        useFlatBlobListing: true,
        blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None).ToList();

    foreach (var src in srcBlobList)
    {
        var srcBlob = src as ICloudBlob;

        // Create appropriate destination blob type to match the source blob
        ICloudBlob destBlob;
        if (srcBlob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.BlockBlob)
            destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
        else
            destBlob = destContainer.GetPageBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);

        // copy using src blob as SAS
        destBlob.BeginStartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken), null, null);          
    }
}
```

The problem is, it's too slow. Waaaay too slow. At the rate it's taking to issue commands to copy all of this stuff, It is going to take somewhere in the neighborhood of four days. I'm not really sure what the bottleneck is (connection limit client side, rate limiting on Azure's end, multithreading, etc).

So, I'm wondering what my options are. Is there any way to speed things up, or am I just stuck with a job that will take four days to complete?

**Edit: How I'm distributing the work to copy everything**

```
//set up tracing
InitTracer();

//grab a set of photos to benchmark this
var photos = PhotoHelper.GetAllPhotos().Take(500).ToList();

//account to copy from
var from = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
    "oldAccount",
    "oldAccountKey");
var fromAcct = new CloudStorageAccount(from, true);
var fromClient = fromAcct.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var fromContainer = fromClient.GetContainerReference("userphotos");

//account to copy to
var to = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
    "newAccount",
    "newAccountKey");
var toAcct = new CloudStorageAccount(to, true);
var toClient = toAcct.CreateCloudBlobClient();

Trace.WriteLine("Starting Copy: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

//enumerate sub directories, then move them to blob storage
//note: it doesn't care how high I set the Parallelism to,
//console output indicates it won't run more than five or so at a time
var plo = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
Parallel.ForEach(photos, plo, (info) =>
{
    CloudBlobDirectory fromDir = fromContainer.GetDirectoryReference(info.BuildingId.ToString());

    var toContainer = toClient.GetContainerReference(info.Id.ToString());
    toContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

    Trace.WriteLine(info.BuildingId + ": Starting copy, " + info.Photos.Length + " photos...");

    BlobHelper.CopyBlobDirectory(fromDir, toContainer, info);
    //this monitors the container, so I can restart any failed
    //copies if something goes wrong
    BlobHelper.MonitorCopy(toContainer);
});

Trace.WriteLine("Done: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you using lots of threads to do it? Most of the time is in the copying. You could parallelise it enormously I think. Maybe with a bunch of worker roles on azure.

Comment: I had the same thought; initially I was running it all synchronously. After some tests, it would have taken nearly two weeks, so I rewrote it to use BeginStartCopyFromBlob(), and wrapped the calls to CopyBlobDirectory() in a Parallel.ForEach. However, the Parallel framework refuses to let me run more than 5 or so jobs at once (even if I set a higher degree); I'm not sure how to force it to run more.

Comment: Could you just spawn lots of threads like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041153/how-to-create-multiple-threads-in-windows-azure-worker-role, say 1000 per worker instance and then spin up a few dozen worker roles?

Comment: I've edited the post to illustrate how I'm managing all the work to do the copying.

Comment: Would you say it takes about 500ms per copy you start?

Comment: More like several seconds, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

The async blob copy operation is going to be very fast within the same data center (recently I copied a 30GB vhd to another blob in about 1-2 seconds). Across data centers, the operation is queued up and occurs across spare capacity with no SLA (see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) which calls that out specifically)

To put that into perspective: I copied the same 30GB VHD across data centers and it took around 1 hour.

I don't know your image sizes, but assuming 500K average image size, you're looking at about 2,000 GB. In my example, I saw throughput of 30GB in about an hour. Extrapolating, that would estimate your 2000 GB of data in about (2000/30) = 60 hours. Again, no SLA. Just a best-guess.

Someone else suggested disabling Nagle's algorithm. That should help push the 4 million copy commands out faster and get them queued up faster. I don't think it will have any effect of copy time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a long shot, but I had a similar issue with table storage whereby small requests (which I think `BeginStartCopyFromBlob` should be) started running extremely slowly. It's a problem with [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and [delayed TCP acks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment), two optimisations for network traffic. See [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx) or [this guy](http://robertgreiner.com/2012/06/why-is-azure-table-storage-so-slow/) for more details.

Upshot - turn Nagle's algorithm off - call the following **before** doing any Azure storage operations.

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

Or for just blob:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
ServicePoint blobServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(account.BlobEndpoint);
blobServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

Would be great to know if that's your problem!

Comment: Trying this; seems to have given it a shot of adrenaline so far :).

Comment: Just remember that the copy operation does not transfer data between storage and your compute instance; this is storage-to-storage, asynchronous copy. The only improvement you'll see, turning Nagle off in this case, is the speed at which each individual copy command is sent/completed. This should allow you to send commands more rapidly.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. The initial problem was figuring out why it was taking so long to even send the requests. Would you happen to know how long it takes for Azure to to actually perform blob copies? Say, a group of 1,000 blobs?

Comment: No SLA on async blob copy across data centers, so I really can't give you a how-long. But... I just posted an answer with a bit of a back-of-the-napkin guesstimate for you based on some performance measurements I took during my own blob-copy work.

Comment: So this did seem to let you queue up those moves in a sensible time-frame (even if the copy will actually take a little longer)? Good to know - this is a weird little quirk with Azure Storage that had me scratching my head for a while....